# Creating Encrypted Tunnel Between 2 Lans

Tags: ethernet, networking, security

I have 2 LANs and one of them is connected to the internet and I need to connect them together. Normally, a single cat6 cable is enough for connection however, this cable is going through a public patch panel which is located on basement(accessible by numerous people).

I want to connect this 2 networks and share internet connection and prevent any sniffing or mitm attacks which can be easily done on this patch panel.

My current configuration is like this.

```
Internet--(cat6)-- router --+--wifi ap
                            +--wifi ap
                            +--vpn server
                            +--printer
                            +--nas
```

seperately;

```
switch---+--wifi ap
         +--wifi ap
         +--wifi ap
         +--computer
         +--computer
```

I need to do this:

```
Internet--router--(cat6)--raspi--(unsafe link-cat6)--raspi--switch
            +--wifi ap                                       +--wifi ap
            +--wifi ap                                       +--wifi ap
            +--vpn server                                    +--wifi ap
            +--printer                                       +--computer
            +--nas                                           +--computer
```

Wifi between two LANs is not possible. I am planning to use usb-ethernet dongles for second lan on raspberry pi. I set up openvpn previously on Raspberry Pi if it is going to help, I am not sure. Required bandwidth is approx. 20 mbits. Encryption doesn't have to be military grade but I am a bit paranoid about it, so more is better.

Any ideas and recommendations are appreciated. I read a lot of things about networks however I couldn't draw a picture in my mind. I have already bought 2 Raspi's for this system however if it's feasible I can use different devices.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I wouldn't use the Pi's for this. I'd use 2 Mikrotik devices. The Mikrotik's can handle multiple ssid's but only one 2.4hgz channel as you have to use virtual ap's in the wifi model. It also has a vpn server and client so you can use L2TP/IPSec over the unsafe link and it has switch chips.

```
Internet--RB2011--(unsafe link-cat6)--RB2011
            +--wifi ap                 +--wifi ap
            +--wifi ap                 +--wifi ap
            +--vpn server              +--wifi ap
            +--printer                 +--computer
            +--nas                     +--computer
```